# What could cause out of control growth of the MessageQueue

Tags: java, android, memory

I implemented an adapter view with a very large dataset (2000+ objects) arranged in a list. Scrolling too fast causes the memory to grow and after analysis with eclipse's MAT, it turns out all of that growth is tied up in the MessageQueue. Below is the specific message:

```
One instance of "android.os.MessageQueue" loaded by "<system class loader>" occupies 57,300,528 (77.75%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "android.os.Message" loaded by "<system class loader>".
```

What are some things that could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by each of the objects spawning an asynctask to grab the image and canceling when the view get recycled. When the list was moving fast enough, these tasks were being created and canceled at a truly frightening pace, resulting in messages everywhere.